# SQL Azure Data Sync vs Standard Geo Replication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync, geo-replication

What is the difference between Data Sync and Standard Geo Replication on SQL Azure databases?

I understand that Active Geo Replication provides the ability to connect to a replicated database whereas Standard does not allow connections.  However, how does Data Sync differ?  I know it's not immediate replication, but I need to point my BI software to a replication and am debating which configuration I use for replication and disaster recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Data Sync allows you specify what to sync (e.g., which tables), specify sync interval (e.g, 5mins, 15mins), replicas are read/write and allows you to specify how to resolve conflicts (e.g., hub wins, client wins), databases can exists independent of other databases.